# DB（MSSQL）からのSELECT結果・列数が予測でない内容を、HTMLでのテーブル出力を達成したい

Tags: php, database

サーバサイドの言語はPHP7.0です。
標題の件を達成する場合、一般的にどういった解決策をとるべきか全く想像がつかず　的を得ない質問をしてしまいました。
しかし皆様からのコメントを得て、自分が分からなくなっているポイントがなんとなくみえてきました。

#### 前提

SELECTから得られる内容は　決して一テーブルからの出力結果に留まらず、参照されるテーブルの全項目でもない、関数で適宜項目が補われている状態、あるテーブルの行分横展開する形態で、列数を予測することができない

#### 分からないポイント

列が可変ということはSQLServerから取得される結果の項目数・項目名が不明なはずで、これらを捉えられなくてはPHPでテーブルに展開できないのでは？という解釈をしていました。
でも、よくよく考えると固定で出力される項目は明らかだし、全ての項目数ってCOUNTやLENGTHで取れるのですよね？実現できそうな気がしてきました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: `SELECT結果・列数が予測でない内容`について、イメージができないので、もう少し具体的に説明てもらえないでしょうか?

Comment: データベースは何ですか？MySQLとかですか？また、今解決しようとしているかと思いますが、PHP越しにクエリでデータ自体は取得出来てますか？実装途中のものでいいのでサンプルコードを質問文に記載できますか？何処で躓いているのかを1つずつ潰した方がいいと思います。今の状態ですと1から10まで説明しなくてはならず回答する範囲が大きすぎます。

Comment: tanalab2様　Myaku様　いつも御世話になっております。
本文に予測不能な列数のSELECT結果という、テーブルに展開したいイメージを貼り付けました。
実際に達成したいこととは異なりますが、イメージを掴んで頂けるようニアリイメージの分かり易い例を
貼り付けました。

DBMSはMS SQServerを想定しています。新たなWebサイトの構築に着手しようとしている段階で、
行の概念を横持ちする手続きが、表示側で克服できるのか否かが分からなくてお問い合わせさせて頂きました。

表示側で克服できないとあらば、DB設計側でなんとか吸収するしかないわけで。

PHPのコーディングに一切入っていません。
開発環境は整っており、MS SQLServerからのデータ取得及び
列固定のテーブルを含むサイトを当該端末で既に構築した経験があります。

Comment: まず、データベース情報は今回の質問の重要なファクターです。埋もれてしまうコメントではなくキチンと質問文中に記載してください。描画をPHPに任せるか、動的にJavaScriptで追加するかは要件で異なる気がしますが、非同期通信でデータを持ってこない限りはPHPが良いと思います。PHPでデータロードの経験があるなら分かるかとは思いますがPHPで連想配列形式でデータベースを取得できます。配列からKey(添え字)一覧も取得できるので表形式で表示するだけなら何も困ることはないかと思いますが、本当に困っているのは`テーブル出力（HTML）`ではなく、データの取得と取りまとめ方なのでは？データの要件が詳しく分からないのですがDBのクエリのみだけでこのサンプル画像のようにJOINできますか？

Comment: 質問の意味が分かりづらく回答がつきにくいと感じました。できれば、一般論的な質問ではなく、具体的な問題について質問を書き直してみてください。また、図でテーブルについて書かれていますが、ぱっと見た感じ何に困っているのかわかりませんでした。ぜひ、例でもいいので 具体的なSQLクエリ、テーブルの定義など書いてみてください。SOでは質問の編集は推奨されていますので、「編集」のリンクを押して 全体的に書き直してみることをおすすめしておきます。そのほうが有益な回答が付きやすくなると思います。SOのヘルプには質問を書く際のガイドラインなどが書かれてますので それらもご参考ください。

Comment: http://www.phppro.jp/phpmanual/php/function.mssql-fetch-field.html などをみると、クエリの結果セットの列情報(列数、列名)は取得できそうですよ。

Answer (score 1):

「追記」部分をみると、「行持ち」のデータ(社員別販売実績テーブル)を「列持ち」のデータとして表現したいという質問に思いました。

「行持ち->列持ち」変換ということであれば、以下のように
`GROUP BY` と `CASE` で実現できます。(同一社員、日付に複数の実績がある場合はMAXではなくSUMに変更)

SQL文のうち、列持ちにするためのCASE文の列を、必要な分だけ動的に作成できれば(例えば、PHPでSQL文を文字列結合などで作成する)、解決できるのではないでしょうか。

```
SELECT
  e.name
  , MAX(CASE WHEN s.sales_date = '2018-07-05' THEN s.amount ELSE NULL END) AS '2018-07-05'
  , MAX(CASE WHEN s.sales_date = '2018-07-06' THEN s.amount ELSE NULL END) AS '2018-07-06'
  , MAX(CASE WHEN s.sales_date = '2018-07-07' THEN s.amount ELSE NULL END) AS '2018-07-07'
  , MAX(CASE WHEN s.sales_date = '2018-07-08' THEN s.amount ELSE NULL END) AS '2018-07-08'
  , MAX(CASE WHEN s.sales_date = '2018-07-09' THEN s.amount ELSE NULL END) AS '2018-07-09'
  , MAX(CASE WHEN s.sales_date = '2018-07-10' THEN s.amount ELSE NULL END) AS '2018-07-10'
  , MAX(CASE WHEN s.sales_date = '2018-07-11' THEN s.amount ELSE NULL END) AS '2018-07-11'
FROM
  sales AS s
JOIN
  employees AS e
ON
s.employee_id = e.id
GROUP BY
  s.employee_id
ORDER BY e.id
```

Comment: 列数が予測できるなら、GROUP BYで横持ちにできると思うのですが。
ということで、Myakeさんのいうとおり、そもそもどうやってそのデータ集団を取得してくるの？？？というところが問題なような気がしてきました。
まずDBMS上で手を動かし、データの集団を捉えてみるべきでした。

Comment: 最初に salesのsales_date列をdistinctして取得すれば、列の候補は取得できるので、その候補をループしてSQL文を作成すれば良いのかと思いました。